# Update object child without id in Firebase function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hope you can help me.

In a trigger of firebase database function I'm trying to update the
object of a child without knowing the id.

[image]

So, I want to update the categoria elements by only knowing the of it, but without knowing the product one.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first retrieve the categoria data. Assuming you know the first key (LNBxRLsPR0OY8-_Cnm) and you have one categoria item only (if more than one categoria will explain with another code snap)

```
firebase.database().ref('product/' + key + '/categoria').once('value', snapshot=>{
  if (snapshot.exists()) var categoriaKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val()[0])
  firebase.database().ref('product/' + key + '/' + categoriaKey).set(newCategoriaObject)
})
```

EDIT:

```
productList={}
firebase.database().ref('product').once('value', snap=>{
   snap.forEach(p=>{
      productList[p.key]=p.val().name; 
   })
})
```

with above product list object array. Scenario:  You will need to show the list of products names to the user. Upon the user selected a product, then you may retrieve the key with below function.

```
function findKey(productList, selectedProductName) { 
     for (let key in productList)
        if (productList[key] === selectedProductName) return key;
}

key = findKey(productList, selectedProductName);
```

So, with the above simple codes, you will get product key, selected by the user. If you don't have another scenario:)

Comment: What if i don't know the product key?

Comment: Then you will retrieve the product key(s) in the same way as the shown code above. At this time you will have a bunch of keys. and you can loop with forEach method all the product keys. ( so first you need to know product key)

Comment: Ok, how can i get the keys in a firebase function?

Comment: You will need each product id or description in order to able to select which product to update. So. you will have two steps. at first steps. you will retrieve products keys and select the product from its id, then you will retrieve the categoria of this product. I will update the code above.

Comment: Totally Works!! Thanks!